# Can TaeBo keep my cardio up?

Tags: cardio, programs, home-exercise

I do TaeBo workout everyday at home, and I want to know if that is good enough or can you point me to another workout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , Tae bo is good enough to keep your cardio up.

***Overview:***

Taebo exercise is a whole body fitness exercise that mixes martial arts moves such as kicks and punches.

***What Are the Benefits of a Blanks Taebo Workout?***

The workouts are high impact which is more stressful on muscles and joints than a low impact routine, although they burn significantly more calories than traditional aerobics. The high impact movements may also help to build stronger bones.

- Building and Toning:

  > Billy says Taebo will work on the upper body (arms, chest, shoulders),
  >   lower body (thighs, buns) and the core muscles (abs, spinal erectors,
  >   obliques). One of the goals of Taebo was to increase functional
  >   strength, which Billy described as the type of strength used on a
  >   daily basis.
- Cardiovascular Workout

  > One of Taebo’s biggest selling points is its cardiovascular workout,
  >   which Billy said was a result of the dance moves added to the already
  >   high-energy workout. The benefit of a good cardiovascular workout was
  >   the first thing Billynoticed when he inadvertently created Taebo in 1976. Billy, a devoted exerciser, became quickly fatigued when combining dance moves to his martial arts and boxing workout.
- Weight Loss

  > Due to the high-energy aerobic nature of Taebo, the exercise program
  >   will burn calories during the routine, which should translate into
  >   weight loss.
- Self Defense

  > The kicking and punching done during a Taebo workout will lead to a
  >   better grasp of self-defense methods. While he says he hopes Taebo
  >   users are never put in a spot where they will need the self-defense
  >   training, Taebo will give them the skills and confidence to deal with
  >   potential trouble.”

***Caution!***

The kicks and punches, particularly the kicks, are intense and can result in significant muscle strain if done too aggressively early on, particularly if incorrect technique is used.

***Conclusion:***

The numerous advantages of Taebo is due to the fact that the discipline is low impact and provides a total body workout. Because this mainly is an aerobic exercise, the heart and lungs benefit a great deal. It may also be noteworthy to point out that boredom with Taebo is less likely to set in because there are several forms of training mixed into it. For those who take pleasure in dancing, Taebo is going to be a first rate exercise alternative. People who favor some type of self defense will like how karate and kickboxing also combine into the program.